# What is the correct function to use DnsQuery or getaddrinfo?

Tags: c++, winapi

I need to translate a hostname to a IPv4 address. For instance, "google.com" to its IPv4 address 172.217.15.78.

What is the correct function to use?

Comment: How portable do you want to be?

Comment: Just for the windows platform, I'm aware that getaddrinfo is Unix and windows.

Comment: Then does it really matter? Use what you feel more comfortable with.

Comment: `getaddrinfo` internal call `DnsQuery`

Comment: I didn't know that, I will fabricate upon DNSQuery as it gives more flexibility. Thanks!

Comment: That is an implementation detail. For general purposes, especially when all you need is hostname resolution, use `getaddrinfo()` instead. DNS is not the only way to resolve a hostname's IP, and `getaddrinfo()` knows that. So let it figure out internally how to resolve the hostname as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all you need is hostname resolution, use `getaddrinfo()`. DNS is not the only way to resolve a hostname's IP address, and `getaddrinfo()` knows that. So let it figure out internally how to resolve the hostname as needed.

Comment: Correct. The obvious example is an `etc/hosts` file, which usually overrides DNS.